# How might I go about analyzing the affect that the number of attempts of something has on the failure rate?

Tags: regression, logistic, poisson-regression, regression-strategies

I have a dataset where I know the number of attempts and number of failures for a large group of individuals. I have calculated the failure rate of each and I suspect that as there are more attempts by an individual, they are less likely to fail. I have the plots below of failure rate vs attempts and another with a log-log scale.
[image: failure rate vs number of attempts]

[image: failure rate vs number of attempts (log-log)]

It seems like there's something going on but many assumptions are not met and all residual diagnostics fail those assumptions as well. One attempt I made, I removed all 0% and 100% ratees as outliers since the vast majority of them occurred when the number of attempts was just 1. Passing this into a linear model with a log-log transform, the qqplot and histogram looked pretty normal but the resid vs fitted was definitely off, but I don't know exactly what causes the behavior (pictured below).

I'm pretty confused about this. I've looked into some GLM options with offsets but I don't understand it fully and I'm not sure how much of it is applicable.

[image: residual vs fitted plot for log-log linear model]